# Using puppeteer to automate button clicks for every button at every URL in a web app

Tags: automation, automated-tests, puppeteer

I am currently trying to use JS and puppeteer to take a screenshot of every url in my web app, as well as take a screenshot of every button that can be clicked.  Is there a way to click each button without specifying the id?  Not all of my buttons have an id and even if they did, I wouldn't want to have x number of page.click(id, options) for each button I have (which is quite a lot).

Thanks

I have tried going based off each className (this app is built using react) but this does not work.  It will take a screenshot of the same buttons over and over.  I believe because if page.click has multiple of the same options, it only chooses the first one and many buttons have the same styling classNames.

Comment: Try focusing on the each button before taking the screenshot. I don't know how to do it in Puppeteer, just giving an idea...

Answer (score 0):

You could get an array of each element on a page, go through the elements with a for loop determine if it is a button, then click it.  Then for each page you'd have to input each url in an array and then use a for loop to go through it.